# Script insert line breaks in div contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, line-breaks

I have a webpage `div` with `contentEditable=true`. After the user modifies the content of the div, the system uses `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` to get the content and send it to server. This is all working:

```
<div id='editBox'; contentEditable='true'></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('editBox').onkeydown=function(e){
    clearTimeout ( backupTimeoutID );
    backupTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){sendDivContentToServer()},3000);
}
<script>
```

the reason I'm using the a div with contentEditable=true instead of text area is that I need to allow displaying and formatting of background-colored text in the div. If I'm unaware of any better way, please, let me know.

My problem is with the inconsistence with which line breaks are displayed. If the user presses return inside the div, it creates another div for the line break. So, when the function gets the innerHtml, it looks like this

```
first line of text<div>second line of text</div>
```

Sometimes, when pasting text from other sources in the edit box (from internet, word, etc), line breaks appear as `<p>`.

I want all line breaks to look like this:

```
first line of text<br>second line of text
```

I have tried changing the behavior of the `<div>` whenever the user presses return; I know the code is working, for if I try to insert a word instead of return it works. But, when I set the code to substitute return for `<br>` it acts erradically. This is the code I'm using for this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('editBox').onkeydown=function(e){
    clearTimeout ( backupTimeoutID );
    backupTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){sendDivContentToServer()},3000);
}
} else if ( pressedKeyCode==13 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand("InsertHTML",false,"a"); // this works
    document.execCommand("InsertHTML",false,"<br>"); // I don't see the effects I want with this
}
<script>
```

Converting the multiple line breaks – `<div>`, `<p>` and `<br>` – seem to be a hard task. Using `<br>` for line breaks seems less error prone.

I'm developing for a web viewer in FileMaker for use in Mac OSX. So, so far, I care more about Safari than any other browser.

Thanks, in advance, for the help.

Comment: See `insertBrOnReturn` in [Command list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands).

Comment: one another way is to let them the way they are and parse them to string with already implemented parsers... what you are doing is partial parsing here on browser, partial parsing there on server... don't play with parsing if you don't have any good reason.

Comment: @teemu not working. I've read that `insertBrOnReturn` is Mozilla specific.

Comment: Indeed, I should have read that page to the end too.

Comment: @Sachin it's a possibility; the problem is FileMaker doesn't have a good parser (that I am aware of). I made the parser so far almost all by myself, and, among other issues, it takes too long to parse. If I could just organize it a little bit better in the browser, things would work better in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reining in `contentEditable` is not an easy task. Unfortunately it's not really standardized and every browser has its quirks.

I would suggest you have a look at the many well written HTML rich text editors that are around.

For example, [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) only creates sensible, valid HTML, it allows you to configure [what happens, when the user presses return](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-enterMode), it can [remove or replace any unwanted HTML](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) and you can disable any features that the user shouldn't use.

Comment: I'm not a master of javascript and html. Do you think working with this editor to make it work as I need would demand expertise in these subjects? I'm more on the noob side of the spectrum.

Comment: Using CKEditor would certainly require less expertise than extending `contentEditable` yourself, and CKEditor has very good documentation, but it's difficult for me to judge it's understandable for a beginner. You could try opening a new question describing what exactly you are doing with the `contentEditable`, especially why and how you (or the user?) are formating the background color. I'm sure someone can either help you configure CKEditor or find a better/easier way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm very grateful for the help. If I can't find another way, I'll probably do this.
The background color is needed; the user is very specific that he wants to be able to "highlight with various colors" and also edit the text again.

Comment: this is the way to go. CKEditor is awesome! Thanks!